# SQL Server 2005 Remote Connection ( Over Internet )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, connection

1. I have installed SQL Server 2005 in mixed mode.
2. I am able to connect to Database "locally" i.e. 
   (Server-name/Instance or internal-ip/Instance) using both kinds of Authentication.
3. I have configured SQL Server for remote connection by following below steps

   Steps:

   - Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you want to connect to from a remote computer.
   - Turn on the SQL Server Browser service.
   - Configure the firewall to allow network traffic that is related to SQL Server and to the SQL Server Browser service. Ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277#method3
4. In addition, I have turned off my firewall.
5. I am able to ping my computer through the External IP.
6. But when it comes to connecting to sql server, its giving the error.

   > "TITLE: Connect to Server
   >
   > Cannot connect to <ip address>\SQLEXPRESS.
   >
   > ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
   >
   > A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)
   >
   > For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

Please help me,
I have referred many article and tested all possible solution, but nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" Sounds like the server has a differen instance name. Can you connect to (local)\SQLEXPRESS on the server itself?

Comment: Have you set up a NAT on the firewall to port forward any traffic coming into the public IP to the correct ports on your internal host? Pinging the public IP means nothing as you're just getting a ping response from the firewall. This really doesn't seem like a good thing to be doing though, exposing SQL server directly to the Internet sounds like a security nightmare.

Comment: Do you have a domain or workgroup, If you have a workgroup both PCs should login with the same username pass, or you should have a saved username,pass on the local computer for your remote connections. before the sql can accept outer connection the OS should accept it

Comment: @steoleary: Thanx for the suggestion.
It's a very late response from my end, but I did some changes in the Router to re-direct the public IP to my machine and few changes in the firewall. It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with Port Forwarding from my Modem/Router to respective Machine IP.

To resolve this issue, I just configured my Router so that it can accept the request on some specific port **[External IP:port_number]** and then map that request to my machine's **[Internal IP:port_number]** as multiple computers were connected to a single router.

Also, please make sure that Firewall on your server is configured correctly to accept the inbound network traffic on that specific port.